# A query put into url to search an object not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i have a database that stores multiple objects. this database is called Houses.
when i send a request to 'localhost:4000/houses', i get a list of all houses (objects). The objects have a key called plus which is a boolean value.
But when i send a request to 'localhost:4000/houses/plus=true', i get all the houses not only the ones whose value of plus is true.

```
{
        
        "plus": false,
        "_id": "5d77b4776b6dd6325ae3018d",                      
        "__v": 0,
       
    }
```

this is what one object looks like, and this is the line that makes the request:

```
axios
        .get('http://localhost:4000/houses?plus=true')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
```

can someone help me? i can't understand my mistake.

Comment: I think that you have to set up the server properly so it returns what you need. Axios will reach the server and will respond with what the server gives to it.

Comment: Are you sure that, on back-end side, the API handles requests with the parameter 'plus'? Can you share the server code handling the GET request?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean, but the request won't even work on Postman